# AIRFLOW - "Oops Something bad has happened"

Tags: airflow

Everything was working just fine with my airflow fresh install, until I got this "Oops something bad has happened" message again. Had it previously when editing the connections.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/auth.py", line 51, in decorated
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 718, in index
    paging=wwwutils.generate_pages(
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 107, in generate_pages
    first_node = Markup(
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 838, in __new__
    warnings.warn(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/warnings.py", line 109, in _showwarnmsg
    sw(msg.message, msg.category, msg.filename, msg.lineno,
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 117, in custom_show_warning
    write_console.print(msg, soft_wrap=True)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1642, in print
    self._buffer.extend(new_segments)
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 842, in __exit__
    self._exit_buffer()
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 800, in _exit_buffer
    self._check_buffer()
  File "/home/mica/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1934, in _check_buffer
    self.file.write(text)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: You likely have no permission to the directory where you write logs. Just check

Comment: I changed them, but get the same output.

Comment: yes same thing happened to me. Was changing from SQLite to Postgres and then back.

Comment: @MMRoller - Any luck with this intermittent error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem happened when I was launching airflow from the home. If you navigate to where the application is and then start the webserver, it worked for me.